# Installed Ubuntu on one drive and left windows 7 on the drive, now can't boot to win7

Tags: dual-boot, windows, boot-repair

Here is my boot-repair report:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/1460148/

I want to be able to dual boot win7 and ubuntu.
When I boot my machine, I see options for ubuntu in grub but no win7.

Do i need to fix my win7 bootmgr and try bootfix as the report suggested?

Cheers
-TD

Comment: follow this"[link][^2]". This should be to solve your problem.
 [^2]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 0):

Set the BIOS boot priority to boot off the second hard drive as suggested.  When ubuntu boots up, open a terminal window and type

```
sudo update-grub
```

and see if the OS prober finds the Windows and insert it into the grub boot menu.  If it does not, then you may have to repair the windows boot files.  It looks like the installer may have tried to put the grub files on the first hard drive.

If you haven't already done so, I'd recommend booting Ubuntu and mounting the first hard drive, then backup any and all important data to something safe, such as an external hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows has missing boot files, you have probably deleted its boot partition by mistake.

**Solution:**

1. Use a Windows disc this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader , until you get direct access to Windows.
2. Then use Boot-Repair's `Recommended Repair` to recover your GRUB menu. It will give access to both Ubuntu and Windows.